# AWS Sagemaker java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have a SageMaker endpoint. The SageMaker endpoint is being invoked via a Lambda function. Part of that Lambda function code that invokes it is:

```
SM_ENDPOINT_NAME = "pytorch-inference-2021-xx-xx"
sm_runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
txt = "Canon Compact Photo Printer"
response = sm_runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=SM_ENDPOINT_NAME, ContentType='text/plain', Body=txt)
print(response)
```

The `response` does not get logged. It is supposed to return a `vector`

When the Lambda function calls the SageMaker endpoint it times out. I started seeing this error suddenly today in the SageMaker Endpoint logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reasonPhrase contains one of the following prohibited characters: \r\n: tokenizers>=0.10.1,<0.11 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found tokenizers==0.11.2.

Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git master
```

For context, The ML Model is supposed to accept a string input and return a `vector` (list). All of my code base is in Python3 . The Java exception seems to be from the SageMaker Backend.

I have not updated the SageMaker endpoint or the Lambda function in a few months. This seems like it has to be an issue with SageMaker.

Is this an issue I can fix or do I need to contact AWS? If so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it appears you are using v0.11.2 of the tokenizers module, and the message indicates you should use a version between 0.10.1 and 0.11.

Try to uninstall the tokenizers module, and then pull an older release via pip...

```
pip install 'tokenizers>=0.10.1,<0.11'
```

Here are all the release versions for reference: https://pypi.org/project/tokenizers/#history

After you update the module, deploy your lambda function again and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Just based on the error message I thought `Tokenizers` was a Java package running in the SageMaker backend. I'm using [Sentence Transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/)
One of their dependencies is `Tokenizers` and it was recently added.
I'll try to manually set the Tokenizer. Thanks!